# Switching scenes in Sprite Kit (Objective C) throws error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am currently having issues switching scenes in Sprite kit. I am calling a method called "enterChurch" that switches scenes to the the churchScene. Here's the code:

```
-(void)enterChurch
{    
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

SKScene *churchScene = [SAFChurchScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
churchScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
self.curScene = churchScene;

[skView presentScene:churchScene];
```

}

When I run it, I get the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't use SKView if you are switching scenes.

Comment: Where are you calling your enterChurch thing?  What's obvious to you is not 100% obvious to others.

Comment: if you are using iAd that can be a common problem, if so search for it on this site

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to switch from one scene in Sprite Kit to Another Scene in sprite kit?

In that case use transitions.

In your current scene.h import ChurchScene.h (or whatever is name of your churchScene.h).
Then add this to your method:

```
-(void)enterChurch
{
SKScene *church = [[ChurchScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0]; //Use any time you like
[self.view presentScene:church transition:transition];
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the cause of a `UIView` object calling a method that an `SKView` should be calling so it doesn't recognize the `@selector`. Check to see in your storyboard that the view inside the view controller is of type `SKView`. It should run